# curl command fails inside docker containers

Tags: linux, docker, curl

I am trying to run curl command to upload a file to destination B inside docker containers but getting the following error message. When I run the same exact command outside the containers on the host server, it works fine. Checked port 443 is open obviously since the curl command works on the host server.

```
* Trying xx.xx.xx.xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to dns.servername.com (xx.xx.xx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; O=WORK; OU=SSL Servers; CN=dns.servername.com
*  start date: Aug 11 19:21:18 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 11 19:51:18 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "dns.servername.com" matched cert's "dns.servername.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=WORK; OU=Certification Authorities; CN=WORK COMPANY Enterprise Issuing CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x561f6445d620)
> POST /service/rest/v1/components?repository=DevOps HTTP/2
> Host: dns.servername.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> accept: application/json
> Authorization: Basic ZmFhZG1pbjotVXUzOEVKKlIhTGMjNXBe
> Content-Length: 368754896
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------cc91de81e54e3bc2
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 104
* Failed sending HTTP2 data
* Connection #0 to host dns.servername.com left intact
curl: (55) SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 104
```

Command I'm running.

```
curl -v 'https://dns.servername.com/service/rest/v1/components?repository=DevOps' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -H 'Authorization: Basic ZmFhZG1pbjotVXUzOEVKKlIhTGMjNXBe' -F 'raw.directory=Folder12345' -F 'raw.asset1=@testfile.zip;type=application/x-zip-compressed' -F 'raw.asset1.filename=testfile.zip'
```

This rarely works maybe one out of 10-20 tries.

Comment: Are you using the same version of curl in docker and directly on the server? What version(s) of openssl are on each one?

Comment: yes, same curl version as well as the openssl version
curl: curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
openssl: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018